# An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am developing a project in react Native. I am using a https url. But it is not working in iOS device. I am getting this error:

```
An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
```

I also added `App Transport Security Settings` in plist. But It is not working.

Here is the plist screenshot.
[image]
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Glenn  Its get url with HTTPS. I also updated the Question. Please check.

Comment: I deleted my comment to give way to other comments. Why not delete that `Exception Domains` and just put `Allow Arbitrary Loads` setting to `YES`?

Comment: @Amit_Chauhan where you able to fix this?

Comment: Probably this can help https://discussions.soti.net/kb/ios-12-devices-fail-to-enroll-with-error-an-ssl-error-has-occurred-and-a-secure-connection-to-the-server-cannot-be-made/